# Nested for loops and object array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

My other question got flagged duplicate couse I didn't explain well enough so i try again only a lot better.

So I'm making this `java` Black Jack console game and have stumbled to a small wall here. I've made a class called `Card` which is ready. Now i'm stumbeling a bit in creating all 52 cards in to an array of cards. Well i made code that works but it seems ugly to me having three nested for loops. Is there a "real way" of doing what I did here.

So here would be part of the class `Card`

```
int value;
String suit;
String name;

public void Card(int value, int suitNumber)
    this.value=value;
    switch(suitNumber){
        case 1 : this.suit = "Heart";
        break;
        .......
    }
switch(value){
case 1 : this.name="Ace";
......
}
```

Part of `Pack` class have a nested for loop like this:

```
 Card[] packOfCards = new Card[51];


 for(int k=0; k<52; ){
     for(int i=1; i<5; i++){
         for(int j=1; j<14; j++){

        packOfCards[k] = Card(j, i);
        k++;

        // it seems stupid for me to have 3 nested
        //loops like that
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see anything truly "wrong" with the way you did this. The only thing I would suggest you look into are `Enumerations`, as both `Suit` and `Name` could be written as such

Comment: I don't think this will work as expected. Looking at it, I think you'll end up with a deck of 52 cards, each with the largest values for `suit` and `value`.

Comment: Not `,` But `;` In For Loop And `Card[52];`

Comment: Yep I just realized what you mean. :p

Comment: 2 nested loops makes sense here. The third is actually wrong. If you run in a debugger you'll notice that packofcards[0] is overwritten 51 times. The loop with k in it should be removed then k should be calculated within the loop (or just use a counter)

Answer (score 1):

You either need to loop over:

- Every slot in your deck
- Every possible card value (Which probably requires a nested loop; get each value for each suit, or vice-versa)

At present you seem to be looping over both.

The following code uses the first approach:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    int suit = (i % 13) + 1;
    int value = (i / 13) + 1;

    packOfCards[i] = new Card(value, suit);
}
```

And this code uses the second (two-loop) approach:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
       int cardIndex = (13 * (i-1)) + j;
       packOfCards[cardIndex] = new Card(j, i);
    }
}
```

Also note that your `Card` class looks wrong. You've declared a `void` method when I think you wanted a constructor, and then you missed the `new` keyword when creating the *new* card (hint: the compiler will alert you to a lot of these mistakes).

As others have suggested, it would probably make more sense to use [`enums`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) too as the type for your card value and suit, rather than juggling between `int` and `String`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Card {

    private final CardValue value;
    private final Suit suit;

    public Card(CardValue value, Suit suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + " of " + suit;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

        for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
            for (CardValue v : CardValue.values()) {
                deck.add(new Card(v, s));
            }
        }

        for (Card c : deck) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        Card aceOfSpades = new Card(CardValue.withValue(1), Suit.SPADES);
        System.out.println(aceOfSpades);
    }

    public enum Suit {
        HEARTS ("Hearts"),
        CLUBS ("Clubs"),
        DIAMONDS ("Diamonds"),
        SPADES ("Spades");

        private final String name;

        Suit(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public enum CardValue {
        TWO(2, "Two"),
        THREE(3, "Three"),
        FOUR(4, "Four"),
        FIVE(5, "Five"),
        SIX(6, "Six"),
        SEVEN(7, "Seven"),
        EIGHT(8, "Eight"),
        NINE(9, "Nine"),
        TEN(10, "Ten"),
        JACK(11, "Jack"),
        QUEEN(12, "Queen"),
        KING(13, "King"),
        ACE(1, "Ace");

        private final int value;
        private final String name;

        CardValue(int value, String name) {
            this.value = value;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static CardValue withValue(int value) {
            for (CardValue v : CardValue.values()) {
                if (value == v.value) {
                    return v;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to pull the `enum`s out into seperate files, but for the sake of producing a relatively concisely working example I put them within the main class.

Comment: Yes I know that there is a bit wrong syntax somewere but I'm writing this from my phone at work. ;D Actually that void I thought that should go there but I have to read more about constructors :)

Comment: Thank you for this. Once I get to my computer I look into it more.

Comment: I tried this on paper and got weird values( like -24) for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    int suit = (i % 13) + 1;
    int value = i - ((i % 13) * 13);

    packOfCards[i] = new Card(value, suit);
}

Comment: @user2365812 Apologies - don't really know what I was trying to do. Corrected (although I'd use the enum approach which means you can loop over `Suit.values()` and `CardValue.values()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get same result using one `for` loop by saving more time complexity instead of three for loop and repeatation. Try,

```
 for (int k = 1; k <= 52; k++) {
   int i = k % 5;
   int j = k % 14;

   packOfCards[k-1] = new Card(j, i);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the best answer but I like it the most. Thank you.

Comment: what about the value of both **i** and **j** starts from **1** in the Question?